# How to return from callback from external script JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I have python-shell configured with nodeJS.
I'm trying to return from the pythonShell by invoking a callback function.
The callback function is successfully able to console log the results from the pythonShell, however, I am unable to return it. I believe this is because the PythonShell.run does not support returns.

```
// Python Invocation
exports.find = function (searchterm) {
  var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

  function callback (err, results) {
    console.log(results); //Exhibit A (logs successfully)
  }

  // PythonShell does not support return
  PythonShell.run('findAnswer.py', callback);

  //How do I return Exhibit A?
};
```

Any tips on this would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You can’t; it doesn’t run synchronously. This is Node’s fundamental… thing. You can modify `exports.find` to accept a callback, or do the right thing and use [promises](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bluebird).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your function as below

```
exports.find = function (searchterm, callback) {
  var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

  // PythonShell does not support return
  PythonShell.run('findAnswer.py', callback);
};
```

and use as below:

```
var finds = require('modulename').find;

finds('search term', function(err, results){
 //do anything with results here
});
```